# How to manually order Typo3 news articles in the list view?

Tags: typo3

I am using the news plugin to simulate the classic page content elements but with previews. Now I would like to be able to manually set the order of the articles just as I would in the page module for the standard elements. But there seems to be no such option in the list module. How would I achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension that adds a sorting field to tt_news so you can order the news entries in the list view. It has not been maintained for quite some time, but since it works on TCA and FlexForm level, it should still work with never versions. Check it out:

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/mpossnewssorting

Comment: I am using the news plugin, not the tt_news.